# Linq to NHibernate using Queryable.Where predicate

Tags: c#, iqueryable, linq-to-nhibernate

I am querying an SQLite database using LINQ to NHibernate.

`Person` is an entity containing an Id and a Name:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Let's say my db table contains a single person whose name is "**John**".

This test works as expected:

```
var query = from item in session.Linq<Person>()
            where (item.Name == "Mike")
            select item;

// no such entity should exist
Assert.IsFalse(query.Any());
```

but this one fails:

```
var query = from item in session.Linq<Person>()
            select item;
query.Where(item => item.Name == "Mike");

// following line actually returns the
// "John" entry
Assert.IsFalse(query.Any());
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Where` doesn't change the existing query, it creates a new one. You need to assign to something if you want to use the new query.

```
var query2 = query.Where(item => item.Name == "Mike");
```

Comment: +1 OMG I can't believe I didn't see that. I need a break. Thanks a lot!